# Disable Rubberband selection in QGraphicsView and only have single item selction

Tags: pyside, qgraphicsview

How can i disable the Rubberband selection in QGraphiscView and only allow users to click select single items as a time in the tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correcly, you want to disable the rubber band selection and still be able to left-click for select items (allowing the Ctrl modifier in order to select multiple items, one at the time).

So if this is the case, you need to use the `QGraphicsView::setDragMode` method and set `QGraphicsView::NoDrag` option. You can achieve this directly from your `QGraphicsView` object or subclassing `QGraphicsView` and adding the call to method on the constructor, like this (PySide):

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).__init__(parent = parent)
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
```

If your graphic items have the `Qt::ItemIsSelectable` flag enabled, then you will still be able to select them as usual.

Hope it helps.